# JetBrains IDE's Run/Debug window lose characters when outputting lone lines

Tags: terminal, output, jetbrains-ide, truncate

I've been troubled by this issue for a long time. GoLand, IDEA, and PyCharm all have this problem: when outputting very long lines (for example, when debugging code locally and needing to output the raw JSON), the IDE automatically wraps the text, but after wrapping, it loses some characters. Running the compiled executable in `macOS's Terminal` or `Terminus` has no issue. Searching Google/YouTrack gives me nothing that helps.

For example, in the image below, after the "product_avg_score" key, there should be a float-type value, and "service_avg_score" is missing the double quotes at the beginning.
[image: Bug Screenshot]

- macOS 13 ARM
- using ZSH with OhMyZSH
- IDE versin from 2022.X ~ 2023.X(latest)

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-280652 -- sounds related to me. **P.S.** https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-212620

Comment: @LazyOne Yeah I visited these issues as well,  on 212620 there's comment says this issue will be fixed in 2023.3 release, but as far as I know only 2023.2.1 available now.